# Spring create list of beans based on properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a simple Spring boot application I have my component like this:

```
@Data
@Component
public class GenericHandler {
    private String path;
    private HandlerType type;
}
```

And my properties might look like this:

```
my.handlers[0].path='/vol1/abc'
my.handlers[0].type='Single'
my.handlers[1].path='/vol1/dora'
my.handlers[1].type='MultiSequence'
```

I tried decorating with the GenericHandler-class with `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.handlers")` and getting a list of all component instances in a service using

```
@Autowired
private List<GenericHandler> handlers;
```

But that created just one component, ignoring the property values at all.

How can I get one component instance per `my.handlers` property-entry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You need a wrapper class

```
    @Component
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.handlers")
    @Data
    public class GenericHandlerWrapper {

      private List<GenericHandler> handlers;
      ...

    }
```

- Then you can `autowire` the `GenericHandlerWrapper`

**Update**

- As `@zoolway` pointed out in the comments, for the properties in the question to work as it is, `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my.handlers")` should be changed to `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")`

Comment: This works if you carefully pay attention to the property hierachy, in this case `GenericHandler` are created for every `my.handlers.handlers`, so `my.handlers.handlers[0],..`. Adopting the naming and hierachy does the job.

Comment: So what would happen if  updated to `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")` , will your properties can be kept as it it is?

Comment: Exactly, that would reflect the necessary hierachy. In general of course the adoption can be done in the properties file or any part of the hierachy.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. What can be done is this:

```
@Data
@Component
public class GenericHandler {
    private List<String> path;
    private List<HandlerType> type;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dealt with a similar issue in a different manner. I created a factory and an interface. The factory would hold different implementations of that interface In your case, `GenericHandler` would be your interface. Then you write any number of implementations of your interface and each implementation is declared as a Component. So, Spring will instantiate it as bean upon a startup (you might use `@Lazy(false)` to force the instantiation at startup) using some infrastructure that I wrote each bean of that interface will self-insert itself into its factory. Then at any part of your code in any bean, you can use the factory to access concrete implementation (base on your property "type" for example). The beauty is that you don't need to inject all the implementations in your bean at the time of writing but access needed implementation dynamically at run-time. I found this to be a useful pattern and created an infrastructure that does most of the work for you and published it as an Open Source library called MgntUtils. The detailed description of the idea (including reference to the library) could be found [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/non-intrusive-access-orphaned-beans-spring-framework-michael-gantman/). Also detailed explanation with examples of how to use it can be found in library Javadoc [here](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/index.html?com/mgnt/lifecycle/management/package-summary.html). The library is available (with source code and Javadoc) as [Maven artifacts](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on the [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases). Also a general article about the MgntUtils library could be found [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/)

Comment: Problem is I do not want to write `n` implementations of the interface, I just need the component multiple times with different parameters. Otherwise an autowired List of interface would have done.

Comment: I see. So you need the same implementation to be instantiated several times as several beans initialized differently according to your props. OK, then my suggestion doesn't resolve your problem.